# Require NSIS High in Authn Request

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I'm using the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 package and have it connected to the Danish NemLog-in 3.
How do I require the NSIS level High in a SAML 2.0 Authn Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `RequestedAuthnContext` to the `Saml2AuthnRequest` and with that add a `AuthnContextClassRef` requiring the NSIS level High (`https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa/High`).
Set the `Comparison` to `Minimum`.

```
var saml2AuthnRequest = new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
{
    RequestedAuthnContext = new RequestedAuthnContext
    {
        Comparison = AuthnContextComparisonTypes.Minimum,
        AuthnContextClassRef = new string[]
        {
            //"https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa/Low"
            //"https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa/Substantial",
            "https://data.gov.dk/concept/core/nsis/loa/High"
        },
    },
};
```

The [code sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L36) is from the [TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp) sample application which is configured with NemLog-in 3 and show how to implement a NemLog-in 3 Service Provider.